# How to get data from client side with odoo rest api server?

Tags: reactjs, odoo

I'm using the rest api odoo server to get content data of a model. I tested on Postman, it works well, 
[image]

but when I integrated into the client side (React app), the request returned an error
[image]

Plz help me solve this problem, maybe the way to add headers at client side is wrong, I handle at front end like this

```
  setAuthorization(token) {
    this.httpClient.defaults.headers.common["access_token"] = token;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: No, I wanna mention to 405 error, If I set access_token to headers, I got the 405 error, but If I remove it, 401 returned

Comment: `401` status code means the request was not authorized. `405` status code means you cannot use this request type to connect to the server. Something like the method which will caught the request is marked as `text/plain` or `application/xml` or another type...

Comment: Consider checking content-type in postman and in your frontend. Most probably you have wrong content-type on front

Comment: I met this post https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/configure-openerp-server-for-cross-domain-9316. I think the problem does not come from the client side

Comment: May I know how did you got accesstoken, ? its official or customized

Comment: @Tejas Tank, it's official, just need to request one api to get token from odoo server

Comment: @HoaiTruong Please give me steps, I might helps you in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it by the way that I allowed method OPTIONS access into the server to check. 
Go to main.py from restful module to change it

```
@http.route(_routes, type="http", auth="none", methods=["GET", "OPTIONS"], csrf=False, cors='*')
```